# Focus ST170 2002 Electric Mirror only works horizontal

Tags: electrical, ford, focus

I am in the UK and drive a 2002 (52 reg) Focus ST170. Recently the electric mirrors would only work vertically intermittently (always worked horizontally), and as of now will not move vertically at all. The vertical movement had been used a lot as I have to parallel park on my street. Both mirrors behave the same which leads me to believe it is not a problem with the motors or mirrors directly. Is this a common fault that I can solve with a switch replacement? Or will I have to go deeper and spend some real time on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is most likely the switch, mainly due to it not working on either mirror. You can more than likely test the switch theory by pulling the switch out and jumping the leads directly to see if movement occurs one either of the mirrors in the direction you desire. I don't have a layout of the wiring, so I would first find where the power lead is at using a multimeter, then use a piece of wire to jump it to the other wires to find out where movement occurs.